# CSS-animation/transform with keyframes in Wordpress-site

Tags: css, wordpress, css-transforms, css-animations

I Have some problems with one of my animations in CSS, but two are working great. They all work great localy, but two dosent work when I put it up on my wordpress page.Someone who knows what the problem is?

My CSS (only with the animation that doesen't work):

```
.start{
-webkit-animation-name: start;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2000ms;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-direction: reverse;

-moz-animation-name: start;
-moz-animation-duration: 2000ms;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-play-state: running;
-moz-animation-direction: reverse;

-ms-animation-name: start;
-ms-animation-duration: 2000ms;
-ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-ms-animation-play-state: running;
-ms-animation-direction: reverse;

animation-name: start;
animation-duration: 2000ms;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-play-state: running;
animation-direction: reverse;


}

@-ms-keyframes start {
from { -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
50% { -ms-transform: translateX(-100px); }
to { -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
}
@-moz-keyframes start {
from { -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
50% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100px); }
to { -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes start {
from { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
50% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px); }
to { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
}
@keyframes start {
from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
50% { 
transform: translateX(-100px); 
}
to {
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
}


/*************************
Animationer - stop
**************************/


.stop{
-webkit-animation-name: start;
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;

-moz-animation-name: start;
-moz-animation-play-state: paused;

-ms-animation-name: start;
-ms-animation-play-state: paused;

animation-name: start;
animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? The first animation works fine, and the second "animation" simply stops the first animation (if the `stop` class is added to that element). Can you provide the HTML and JS or describe the problem more in depth? What are you attempting to accomplish with these effects?

Comment: Im sorry if I wasn't that clear, I didnt take the ones that workes in the code. Only the two animations that dosent work (or one animation that I stop in the second part).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kmblackwood/5v5F4/

From what I can tell, the first one works, and the second one seems to be a way to trigger a pause on the first animation. Maybe having the HTML or JS (if any) would help make it clearer.

Comment: It works when I do it outside of Wordpress, but it dosent work in wordpress. So I'm looking for a clue to why that is and how I can fix that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sorry, a bit of sleep did me well. Found that it was just a little bit wrong in my javascript-code. Dont know why it worked anyway on my cumputer (outside of wordpress), but at least I found the problem now!